# Python dictionary empties in some cases when passed between functions

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have a dictionary that needs to be referred to by other functions. Rather than make it global, I pass the dictionary as an argument.

```
def functionA(dictionary):
    dictionary = {}
    functionB(dictionary)
    print(f"In A, after B, length: {len(dictionary)}")

def functionB(dictionary):
    dictionary["A"] = "some value"
    dictionary["B"] = "another value"

def main():
    dictionary = {}
    functionA(dictionary)
    print(f"Back in main. Length: {len(dictionary)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """ This is executed when run from the command line """
    main()
```

In the above code, `main()` initializes `dictionary` as empty and passes it to `functionA()`, which also (redundantly) sets it to empty and passes it to `functionB()`, which adds a couple of entries.

After `main()` returns from `functionA()`, I expected `dictionary` to have the two entries added by `functionB()`. However, it was empty. The output was:

```
In A, after B, length: 2
Back in main. Length: 0
```

If, however, I remove the redundant `dictionary = {}` in `functionA` (i.e., the second line of the above code block), the problem goes away and I get the following output:

```
In A, after B, length: 2
Back in main. Length: 2
```

I don't see why the `dictionary = {}` statement in `functionA()` causes the subsequently added items to not get transferred back to `main()`. Any insights? I feel like there's something fundamental here that I'm clueless about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical thing is that `dictionary = {}` does *not* empty the original dictionary.  It instead creates a *new* dictionary.  This is more easily seen if we bind the original dictionary to a different name:

```
def functionA(dictionary):
    original = dictionary
    dictionary = {}
    functionB(dictionary)
    print(f"In A, after B, length: {len(dictionary)}")
    print(f"Original argument: {len(original)}")
```

```
In A, after B, length: 2
Original argument: 0
Back in main. Length: 0
```

The original dictionary that was created in `main` and passed to `functionA` is never modified, and so it is still empty.  The `dictionary` inside `functionA` which was passed to `functionB` is an entirely new object (separate from `original`) that `main` has no way of accessing because it was never `return`ed.

If you want to modify the original dictionary by passing around references to it, you need to make sure that you use mutator methods instead of rebinding the name, e.g.:

```
def functionA(dictionary):
    dictionary.clear()
    functionB(dictionary)
    print(f"In A, after B, length: {len(dictionary)}")
```

```
In A, after B, length: 2
Back in main. Length: 2
```

You can also avoid this type of confusion by always `return`ing whatever data you want the caller to receive:

```
def functionA(dictionary):
    dictionary = {}
    dictionary = functionB(dictionary)
    print(f"In A, after B, length: {len(dictionary)}")
    return dictionary

def functionB(dictionary):
    dictionary["A"] = "some value"
    dictionary["B"] = "another value"
    return dictionary

def main():
    dictionary = {}
    dictionary = functionA(dictionary)
    print(f"Back in main. Length: {len(dictionary)}")
```

```
In A, after B, length: 2
Back in main. Length: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

`functionA` reassigns the `dictionary` name to a *new* piece of memory that is distinct from the memory referred to in the parameter.

Your code is logically equivalent to:

```py
def functionA(dictionary):
    dictionary_a = {}
    functionB(dictionary_a)
    print(f"In A, after B, length: {len(dictionary_a)}")

def functionB(dictionary):
    dictionary["A"] = "some value"
    dictionary["B"] = "another value"

def main():
    dictionary = {}
    functionA(dictionary)
    print(f"Back in main. Length: {len(dictionary)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """ This is executed when run from the command line """
    main()
```

which should make the issue more readily apparent.

You can think of the `dictionary` in `main()` and the `dictionary` in `functionA` as two separate references to the same dictionary. When `dictionary` in `functionA` is reassigned, it doesn't affect the value of `dictionary` in `main()`. As a rule of thumb, [reassignment only affects the name that you put on the left-hand side of the statement](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).